# How to get vectorLeft value from GLKVector2 in iOS?

Tags: ios

Now I am working on a simple game. I use GLKVector2 to add two vector values like A and B. A vector result, like (58.8717, 156). Then, I want to get the first value in 58.8717 but I don't know how to get it.

```
GLKVector2 position = GLKVector2Add(A, B);  
NSLog(@"Position:%@",NSStringFromGLKVector2(position));
//NSLog value - Position:{58.8717, 156}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the first value, you have to look for `position.x`.

```
NSLog(@"Position:%f",position.x);
```

The line above will log the expected result.